# SharePoint 2013 - Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you

Tags: 2013, access-denied

I am a SysAdmin currently having an issue with a new deployment of SharePoint 2013.

I am getting "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you" when trying to browse to the site collection. This happens for the farm user and site collection admin. I have tried re-installing SharePoint and also installing it on another server.

I have tried both NTLM & Kerberos Authentication, using different site templates, reinstalling SharePoint with only the farm account (I usually have different accounts for IIS pools & Services). If I try to make any site collections or new pages the same thing happens. (Can still get to /_layouts/settings.aspx)

I am able to get to /_Layouts/settings.aspx and can view all the settings the Site Collection Administrator has, I am able to get to pages by their full path address. e.g /servername/SitePages/home.aspx. this only seems to be an issue when going to a page which the redirects you to another page (if that makes sense)

Looking in ULS logs & FIddler there doesn't seem to be any errors. Basically the user hits / and then gets redirected to the Sorry this site hasn't been shared with you page.

I'm trying to access the site using the hostname. So let's say servername:80.
I don't have access to add anything else into DNS at the moment.
I have also tried doing websitename:80 and added the IP and websitename into another server host files and I get the same error.

Comment: have you cross verified the DB permissions for all service accounts especially content db.

Comment: I have currently set the farm up only using the farm account for Farm & WebApp (For Testing purposes at the moment) and that account has db_owner on all the content databases.

Comment: looks you are the victim of Object Cache, did you configure the Object cache on the web app..super user and super reader?

Comment: No, I've left them as the default accounts. From my understanding this can be left as default if you want (In this farm at least). In my old farm I had set the accounts correctly (Using PowerShell and in the User Policy)